# HTML form not sending data via $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to send some basic form information from my index page to a .php page without success. I have tweaked my code looking at the previously asked questions but to no avail.

I have another form on the same page which sends information to another .php page which works without flaw.

My form page code:

```
 <form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>email: <input type="text" name="loginEmail"></p><br>
        <p>password: <input type="password" name="loginPass"></p>
        <button type="submit"> Submit!</button>
    </form>
```

my login.php page code:

```
 <?php
echo "test";
$email=$POST_["loginEmail"];
echo $email;
?>
```

All I see on my login.php page is "test".
Thanks.

Comment: It's `$_POST`, not `$POST_`

Comment: You got it right in your title but wrong in your code :/

Comment: Yikes!, Thanks very silly mistake. 2am coding :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching the location of the `_` should do it:

```
<?php
echo "test";
$email=$_POST["loginEmail"];
echo $email;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, a very careless mistake on my end.